# Problem in setting GUI to Ubuntu 14.04-Failed to fetch problem

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, gui

I installed latest Ubuntu server (14.04 LTS) and tried to make a desktop envt using

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

But it shows

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/dists/trusty/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/dists/trusty-updtes/InRelease

.
.
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I saw several questions have been asked and I tried  some of those  without success.

The last one I tried as follows

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

The above command removed some packages but again failed on apt-get update.

Can anyone direct me how to overcome this problem to successfully enable a desktop envt to my server?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr3kw.jpg) for grep -r 'us.archive.ubuntu.com' /etc/apt

Edit

[sudo sed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39oX4.jpg) command result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a network problem. The `InRelease` thing is the consequence. Your system can't fetch the GPG key and for this reason it tries to use the `InRelease` file instead of the `Release` file and of course, also fails.

> InRelease files are signed in-line while Release files should have an accompanying Release.gpg file.

<sub>[Source](https://wiki.debian.org/RepositoryFormat)</sub>